# метод __iter__ и __next__ в классе

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Как реализовать его в классе чтоб он  итерировал переданный классу файл, а точнее строки в файле.

```
for i in File('text.txt'):    #экземпляр класса
    print(i)                  # принтит строки в файле 'text.txt
```

непонятно именно с магическими методами

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self
def __next__(self):
    pass
```

что сюда писать

Comment: Очевидно, `__next__` должен возвращать строку. В чём затруднения?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте:

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_obj = open(file_name)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.file_obj

# OR:
class File:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_obj = open(file_name)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.file_obj)
```

Использование:

```
for i in File('text.txt'): # экземпляр класса
    print(repr(i))         # принтит строки в файле 'text.txt
```

---

**UPD.** Текущая реализация, хоть и наглядно отвечает на вопрос, но не закрывает файл, что плохо, поэтому по совету **jfs**:

> чтобы утечку ресурсов избежать, лучше открытый файл принимать (тогда
> тот кто его передаёт будет отвечать за закрытие файла) или реализовать
> .close, ._*enter*_, ._*exit*_ методы.

Comment: чтобы утечку ресурсов избежать, лучше открытый файл принимать (тогда тот кто его передаёт будет отвечать за закрытие файла) или реализовать `.close`, `.__enter__`, `.__exit__` методы.

Comment: @jfs, согласен, добавлю в ответ

Answer (score 0):

Ребята не придумывайте велосипеды. Файлы их коробки поддерживают протокол итераций и позволяют итерироваться по строкам.

```
f = open(r'file.txt')
for s in f:
    print(s)
```

Comment: Думаю автор вопроса понимает, что это доступно из коробки, но своя реализация нужна для тренировки :)